# upload file use uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile: in background and use multipart/form-data

Tags: objective-c, multipartform-data, background-task

here is the situation:

1. my server only accept **multipart/form-data** upload action.
2. my app need to implement **background upload**.

I've tried below:

1. if I ignore `background`, I can use `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData:`, build all boundary, content-disposition, and file data, then upload to a supported server. and I do successfully have done this. `BUT` I need to use background transfer.
2. if I force this method in background mode, I got an error: `Upload tasks from NSData are not supported in background sessions.`
3. if I use background mode, and use `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:`, I got something like '`stream ended unexpectedly`' from the server, as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913436/unable-to-upload-file-using-nsurlsession-multi-part-form-data-in-ios/37096111#37096111) mentions, the best answer suggest people to use `fromData` which apparently is not my need.

so is there any way to accomplish this? since the server can't change it's support, I **NEED** background transportation and multipart/form-data content-type both.

Comment: The third point could indicate to a syntactic error in your form data. Have you tried to upload this data with a command line tool like `curl` or `nc`?

Comment: @macmoonshine the thing is , I successfully upload my file by use `fromData` method, which I generate all multi-part data by code. and use `fromFile` method, you don't need to generate data, so why should I test this `data` or how could I test the `data`. and I logged the request , the `fromFile` method even didn't send any body-data, body-stream and content-length, so, why does this method exists...or should build some other things by code? where is the doc or demo?...

Comment: The file should contain your form data, and you should test this file with `curl`. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @macmoonshine thanks, but it's seems a NSURLSession's bug, I solved this by write upload file to a temp file use a AF's convenient method. [see](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1874)

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I figure out it's a NSURLSession bug, from this [issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1874), I find a way to upload file with `fromFile` method successfully (and many SO answers used that already, but it's still not shown in AFNetworking's document.

you just need to write your file to a temp file, and use AF's convenient method the build the `multipart` part. the backend reason you can find out yourself, here's my code

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *multipartRequest = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]
                                     multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                     URLString:[url absoluteString]
                                     parameters:nil
                                     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
                                         [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filename]
                                                                    name:@"file"
                                                                fileName:short_name
                                                                mimeType:@"application/octet-stream"
                                                                   error:nil];
                                     } error:nil];

[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMultipartFormRequest:multipartRequest writingStreamContentsToFile:[NSURL URLWithString:temp_file_name] completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [bgsession uploadTaskWithRequest:multipartRequest
                                                       fromFile:[NSURL URLWithString:temp_file_name]
                                              completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:temp_file_name error:nil];
                                                  NSLog(@"=========response=========\n%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                              }];
[task resume];
}];
```

Comment: we also need to do code in appdelegate handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession too to finish this request, correct?

Comment: @iChirag that's background thing, not the upload bug. you will still do all things that this feature needs by yourself.

Comment: @walker, i've tried to use your solution but got an error on writingStreamContentsToFile. could you share me full code for file upload ?